# Rotating speed of a cannon

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In the current app i'm making, i'm using a cannon shoot balls at the targets but the cannon rotates too fast. When i touch the screen the cannon rotates in a counter clockwise direction quickly, i would like to reduce the rotation speed.I set the angulardamping to 100 but the speed doesn't seem to change a bit.

```
function charge()
     cannon.angularDamping = 100
     cannon.rotation = cannon.rotation - 5
     impulse=impulse-0.2

     if(cannon.rotation < -46) then
          cannon.rotation = -46
          impulse = -3.2
     end
end
```

Comment: Are you moving the cannon as an object or a physics object?  AngularDamping deals with objects that are being used in the Physics engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current rotation speed of your cannon is 5 degrees per frame (assuming you call `charge()` as part of an `enterFrame` handler) because you have this:

```
cannon.rotation = cannon.rotation - 5
```

So if you want it to rotate more slowly try any of the following:

```
local degreesPerFrame = 1 -- or 0.1 or whatever, try several
cannon.rotation = cannon.rotation - degreesPerFrame
```

If you want a specific speed, then you can get the time since last `enterFrame` via `event.time - appStartTime`. Then you would use

```
function enterFrame(event)
    if appStartTime == nil then 
         appStartTime = event.time
    else
         deltaTime = event.time - appStartTime
         charge(deltaTime)
    end
end

function charge(deltaTime) 
    local degreesPerSec = 1 -- or 0.1 or whatever, try several
    cannon.rotation = cannon.rotation - degreesPerSec * deltaTime
    ...
end
```

Alternately you could make your object a kinematic physics body (note: not dynamic):

```
physics.addBody(cannon, "kinematic", {isSensor = false})
cannon.angularVelocity = 1 -- deg/s
```

However you seem to have dynamics in your code. If your object is a "dynamic" physics object (created with "dynamic" instead of "kinematic") then have to apply a torque in order to make it turn. A constant torque will cause a non-zero angular acceleration, i.e. will cause the angular velocity to increase as long as the torque is applied, unless there is velocity dependent damping, then there is usually a maximum where damping counteracts torque exactly and the object reaches a steady angular velocity.

Using a dynamic object will give you smoother, more realistic changes, but may be overkill in the case of a cannon. I would stick to kinematic or no physics at all, just changing the rotation value.

Answer (score 0):

`angularDamping` decreases physics body angular velocity.

If you set body rotation directly, it will do nothing.

Try to use `canon:applyAngularImpulse(-5)`, to rotate it and look how angularDamping reduces rotation speed. Do not touch rotation manually.

You can also use motor or revolure joint, to control canon rotation precisely.